# How to disable div(s) until previous div has been filled in

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a drag and drop quiz, as a start I have four questions in which answers can be picked up and dropped into the corresponding question. I want to disable the drop box for questions 2,3,4 until question 1 is answered. Then re-active q2 leaving 3,4 disabled and so on.... I'm quite new to JavaScript and have tried multiple ways to do this, including looking at other situations similar to mine on here but have yet succeeded! I have put a screenshot of the quiz so far which will hopefully make it clearer.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

All my code is below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="draganddrop.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>SAN Failure</h1>
        <p>Your SAN&#39;s RAID controller has failed and corrupted a significant amount of data.  You need to contact your DR provider failover to your recovery environment whilst you restore your internal servers from backup images.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="dragScriptContainer">
            <div id="questionDiv">
                <p><strong>Task one: Damage Control</strong></p>

                <div class="dragDropSmallBox textbox" id="q1">1. Find the relevant IP address for the affected hardware</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>
                <div class="dragDropSmallBox textbox" id="q2">2. Notify your disaster recovery provider</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>
                <div class="dragDropSmallBox textbox" id="q3">3. Inform the team of directors of the situation</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>
                <div class="dragDropSmallBox textbox disabled="true"" id="q4">4. Update the emergency phone message</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="feedback">
                <div id="feedback"></div>
                <div id="counter">0</div>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">

                <h1 style="text-align:center">Disaster Recovery Runbook</h1>

                <!-- Page 1 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 1</h5>
                <h2>Executive Summary</h2>
                <p>[ACME Ltd. company information]<br>ACME Ltd. currently has 9 virtual servers and 4 physical servers all hosted at an onsite data centre.<br>The key IT staff required for recovery are [IT Manager], [Backup Manager] and [Disaster Recovery Provider]. The servers must be recovered within 8 hours of invocation. 
                </p>

                <!-- Page 2 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 2</h5>
                <h2>Contents</h2>
                <p><strong>
                    Invoking Disaster Recovery<br>
                    Key Contacts<br>
                    Call Tree<br>
                    Emergency Phone Message<br>
                    Network Diagram<br>
                    Recovery Locations<br>
                    Software License and Registration Keys<br>
                    Event Log<br>
                    Recovery Templates
                </strong></p>

                <!-- Page 3 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 3</h5>
                <h2>Invoking Disaster Recovery</h2>
                <p>If a crisis or disaster has occurred, the business continuity manager must decide the course of action. If, for whatever reason, the business continuity manager is unable to perform these duties, refer to the cascading decision-making hierarchy below.<br>Only the most senior member is authorized to invoke the DR plan, subject to availability.<br>1. Business Continuity Manager<br>2. IT Director<br>3. IT Manager<br>4. IT Administrator<br>In the event none of the stated staff members are available&#46;&#46;&#46;good luck.</p>
                <div id="answerDiv">
                <!-- Page 4 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 4</h5>
                <h2>Key Contacts</h2>
                <main class="flex-center">

                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p><strong>Contact</strong></p></td>
                                <td><p><strong>Telephone Number</strong></p></td>
                                <td><p><strong>Email Address</strong></p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Managing Director</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a3">0123456789</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">M.D@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Financial Director</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">1234567890</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">F.D@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Business Continuity Manager</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">2345678901</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">B.C.D@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Sales Manager</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">3456789012</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">S.M@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Production Manager</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">4567890123</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">P.M@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>HR Director</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">5678901234</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">H.R.D@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Backup Manger</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">6789012345</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">B.M@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Power Supplier</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">7890123456</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">P.S@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Internet Supplier</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">8901234567</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">I.S@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Disaster Recovery Supplier</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a2">9012345678</div></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">D.R.S@acme.com</div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </main>

                <!-- Page 5 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 5</h5>
                <h2>Call Tree</h2>
                <img class="callTree" src="img/call_tree.jpg">

                <!-- Page 6 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 6</h5>
                <h2>Emergency Phone Message</h2>
                <p>We have distributed emergency call cards to staff, containing the number for an emergency phone line in a disaster. You should update this message to alert your staff members to the presence of a disastrous event, and every time there is a change in circumstances &#45; either towards or away from resolution.<br> To update the message call the number below:</p>


                <div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a4">UPDATE EMERGENCY PHONE LINE</div><br><br>

                <!-- Page 7 -->
                <h5 style="color: red; ">Page 7</h5>
                <h2>Network Diagram with Service Information</h2>
                <main class="flex-center">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p><strong>Service</strong></p></td>
                                <td><p><strong>IP Address</strong></p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Email</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">192.0.0.1</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Web Server</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">192.0.0.2</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>MPLS</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">192.0.0.3</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>VoIP</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">192.0.0.4</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>SAN Server</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a1">192.0.0.5</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>CRM Server</p></td>
                                <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox" id="a10">192.0.0.6</div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                </main>

</div>


    <div id="dragContent"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <input type="button" onclick="dragDropResetForm();return false" value="Reset">
                <input type="button" onclick="clearFields();" id="clear" value="Clear">
                <input type="button" onclick="showResults();" id="result" value="Result">
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var shuffleQuestions = true;
var shuffleAnswers = false;
var lockedAfterDrag = true;

function quizIsFinished()
{   
    alert('Finished!');
}

var dragContentDiv = false;
var dragContent = false;

var dragSource = false;
var dragDropTimer = -1;
var destinationObjArray = new Array();
var destination = false;
var dragSourceParent = false;
var dragSourceNextSibling = false;
var answerDiv;
var questionDiv;    
var sourceObjectArray = new Array();
var arrayOfEmptyBoxes = new Array();
var arrayOfAnswers = new Array();

function getTopPos(inputObj)
{       
    if(!inputObj || !inputObj.offsetTop)return 0;       
    var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
    while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null)returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
    return returnValue;
}

function getLeftPos(inputObj)
{
    if(!inputObj || !inputObj.offsetLeft)return 0;  
    var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
    while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null)returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;
    return returnValue;
}

function cancelEvent()
{
    return false;
}

function initDragDrop(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;
    if(lockedAfterDrag && this.parentNode.parentNode.id=='questionDiv')return;
    dragContentDiv.style.left = e.clientX  + Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollLeft) + 'px';
    dragContentDiv.style.top = e.clientY  + Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop,document.body.scrollTop) + 'px';
    dragSource = this;
    dragSourceParent = this.parentNode;
    dragSourceNextSibling = false;
    if(this.nextSibling)dragSourceNextSibling = this.nextSibling;
    if(!dragSourceNextSibling.tagName)dragSourceNextSibling = dragSourceNextSibling.nextSibling;

    dragDropTimer=0;
    timeoutBeforeDrag();

    return false;
}

function timeoutBeforeDrag(){
    if(dragDropTimer>=0 && dragDropTimer<10){
        dragDropTimer = dragDropTimer +1;
        setTimeout('timeoutBeforeDrag()',10);
        return;
    }
    if(dragDropTimer>=10){
        dragContentDiv.style.display='block';
        dragContentDiv.innerHTML = '';
        dragContentDiv.appendChild(dragSource);

    }       
}

function dragDropMove(e)
{
    if(dragDropTimer<10){
        return;
    }

    if(document.all)e = event;

    var scrollTop = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop,document.body.scrollTop);
    var scrollLeft = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollLeft);

    dragContentDiv.style.left = e.clientX + scrollLeft + 'px';
    dragContentDiv.style.top = e.clientY + scrollTop + 'px';

    var dragWidth = dragSource.offsetWidth;
    var dragHeight = dragSource.offsetHeight;


    var objFound = false;

    var mouseX = e.clientX + scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = e.clientY + scrollTop;

    destination = false;
    for(var no=0;no<destinationObjArray.length;no++){
        var left = destinationObjArray[no]['left'];
        var top = destinationObjArray[no]['top'];
        var width = destinationObjArray[no]['width'];
        var height = destinationObjArray[no]['height'];

        destinationObjArray[no]['obj'].className = 'destinationBox';
        var subs = destinationObjArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('DIV');
        if(!objFound && subs.length==0){
            if(mouseX < (left/1 + width/1) && (mouseX + dragWidth/1) >left && mouseY < (top/1 + height/1) && (mouseY + dragHeight/1) >top){
                destinationObjArray[no]['obj'].className='dragContentOver';
                destination = destinationObjArray[no]['obj'];                   
                objFound = true;
            }       
        }   
    }

    sourceObjectArray['obj'].className='';

    if(!objFound){
        var left = sourceObjectArray['left'];
        var top = sourceObjectArray['top'];
        var width = sourceObjectArray['width'];
        var height = sourceObjectArray['height'];

        if(mouseX < (left/1 + width/1) && (mouseX + dragWidth/1) >left && mouseY < (top/1 + height/1) && (mouseY + dragHeight/1) >top){
            destination = sourceObjectArray['obj'];
            sourceObjectArray['obj'].className='dragContentOver';
        }
    }
    return false;
}


function dragDropEnd()
{
    if(dragDropTimer<10){
        dragDropTimer = -1;
        return;
    }
    dragContentDiv.style.display='none';
    sourceObjectArray['obj'].style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
    if(destination){
        destination.appendChild(dragSource);
        destination.className='destinationBox';


        if(!destination.id || destination.id!='answerDiv'){
            var previousEl = dragSource.parentNode.previousSibling;
            if(!previousEl.tagName)previousEl = previousEl.previousSibling;
            var numericId = previousEl.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
            var numericIdSource = dragSource.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

            if(numericId==numericIdSource){
                dragSource.className='correctAnswer';
                checkAllAnswers();  
            }

            else
                dragSource.className='wrongAnswer'; 

        }

        if(destination.id && destination.id=='answerDiv'){
            dragSource.className='dragDropSmallBox';
        }

    } else{
        if(dragSourceNextSibling)
            dragSourceNextSibling.parentNode.insertBefore(dragSource,dragSourceNextSibling);
        else
            dragSourceParent.appendChild(dragSource);
    }

    if(numericId==numericIdSource) {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML += 'Correct Answer!';

    } 

    else {
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML += 'Incorrect Answer! Have you tried this...';
        incrementScore();
    }

        dragDropTimer = -1;
        dragSourceNextSibling = false;
        dragSourceParent = false;
        destination = false;
    }


    function checkAllAnswers()
    {   
        for(var no=0;no<arrayOfEmptyBoxes.length;no++){
            var sub = arrayOfEmptyBoxes[no].getElementsByTagName('DIV');
            if(sub.length==0)return;

            if(sub[0].className!='correctAnswer'){
                return;
            }   

        }   

        quizIsFinished();   
    }

    function resetPositions()
    {
        if(dragDropTimer>=10)return;

        for(var no=0;no<destinationObjArray.length;no++){
            if(destinationObjArray[no]['obj']){
                destinationObjArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(destinationObjArray[no]['obj'])
                destinationObjArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(destinationObjArray[no]['obj'])  
            }       

        }
        sourceObjectArray['left'] = getLeftPos(answerDiv);
        sourceObjectArray['top'] = getTopPos(answerDiv);        
    }


    function initDragDropScript()
    {
        dragContentDiv = document.getElementById('dragContent');

        answerDiv = document.getElementById('answerDiv');
        answerDiv.onselectstart = cancelEvent;
        var divs = answerDiv.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
        var answers = new Array();

        for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
            if(divs[no].className=='dragDropSmallBox'){
                divs[no].onmousedown = initDragDrop;
                answers[answers.length] = divs[no];
                arrayOfAnswers[arrayOfAnswers.length] = divs[no];
            }

        }   

        if(shuffleAnswers){
            for(var no=0;no<(answers.length*10);no++){
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
                answerDiv.appendChild(answers[randomIndex]);
            }       
        }

        sourceObjectArray['obj'] = answerDiv;
        sourceObjectArray['left'] = getLeftPos(answerDiv);
        sourceObjectArray['top'] = getTopPos(answerDiv);
        sourceObjectArray['width'] = answerDiv.offsetWidth;
        sourceObjectArray['height'] = answerDiv.offsetHeight;


        questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');

        questionDiv.onselectstart = cancelEvent;
        var divs = questionDiv.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

        var questions = new Array();
        var questionsOpenBoxes = new Array();


        for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
            if(divs[no].className=='destinationBox'){
                var index = destinationObjArray.length;
                destinationObjArray[index] = new Array();
                destinationObjArray[index]['obj'] = divs[no];
                destinationObjArray[index]['left'] = getLeftPos(divs[no])
                destinationObjArray[index]['top'] = getTopPos(divs[no])
                destinationObjArray[index]['width'] = divs[no].offsetWidth;
                destinationObjArray[index]['height'] = divs[no].offsetHeight;
                questionsOpenBoxes[questionsOpenBoxes.length] = divs[no];
                arrayOfEmptyBoxes[arrayOfEmptyBoxes.length] = divs[no];
            }
            if(divs[no].className=='dragDropSmallBox'){
                questions[questions.length] = divs[no];
            }

        }

        if(shuffleQuestions){
            for(var no=0;no<(questions.length*10);no++){
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);

                questionDiv.appendChild(questions[randomIndex]);            
                questionDiv.appendChild(questionsOpenBoxes[randomIndex]);       

                destinationObjArray[destinationObjArray.length] = destinationObjArray[randomIndex];
                destinationObjArray.splice(randomIndex,1);  

                questionsOpenBoxes[questionsOpenBoxes.length] = questionsOpenBoxes[randomIndex];
                questionsOpenBoxes.splice(randomIndex,1);
                questions[questions.length] = questions[randomIndex];
                questions.splice(randomIndex,1);    


            }       
        }

        questionDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        answerDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

        document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd;   
        document.documentElement.onmousemove = dragDropMove;    
        setTimeout('resetPositions()',150);
        window.onresize = resetPositions;
    }

    function incrementScore(){
        counter = document.getElementById('counter');
        counter.innerHTML++;
    }

    function showResults() {

        result = document.getElementById('result');

        if(counter.innerHTML < 2){
            result.innerHTML += 'Well done!';
        } else {
            result.innerHTML += 'Not so great!';
        }
    }

    /* Reset the form */
    function dragDropResetForm()
    {
        for(var no = 0; no < arrayOfAnswers.length; no++){
            arrayOfAnswers[no].className='dragDropSmallBox'
            answerDiv.appendChild(arrayOfAnswers[no]);              
        }

        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "";

    }

    function clearFields() {
        document.getElementById("questionDiv").innerHTML = "";

    }

    window.onload = initDragDropScript;
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the minimum necessary for your question. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Comment: And what do you mean by "disable" a div?  A div is a box, essentially.

Comment: the user can drag an answer into a grey div box, I wanted to know if it was possible to disable this until the answer to the previous question has been submitted, i've added an image to try and make the explanantion clearer

Comment: try detecting when each field's value changes, and then iterate through all fields, checking each to see if it is empty, until you find an empty one, at which point you have found your empty one, and unhide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use jQueryUI [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert) interactions to achieve what you want. They contain many methods and events which you can use, for example you can easily disable a droppable object by using `$( ".selector" ).droppable( "disable" );`. You can also save yourself the trouble of creating methods for dragging the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a very basic example that should help you out, however it can be improved :)

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/hoeh0hds/1/

html

```
<input id="input1" />
<br />
<input id="input2" />
<br />
<input id="input3" />
<br />
<input id="input4" />
<br />
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('input2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('input3').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('input4').disabled = true;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    inputs[index].addEventListener('input', function () {
        // Input 1
        if (this == document.getElementById('input1')) {
            if (this.value.length) {
                document.getElementById('input2').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('input2').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('input3').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('input4').disabled = true;
            }
        }

        // Input 2
        if (this == document.getElementById('input2')) {
            if (this.value.length) {
                document.getElementById('input3').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('input3').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('input4').disabled = true;
            }
        }

        // Input 3
        if (this == document.getElementById('input3')) {
            if (this.value.length) {
                document.getElementById('input4').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('input4').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion! just one question, in my current piece of work I have used divs rather than inputs because it has a drag and drop functionality.... I didn't think this was possible with inputs? @Canvas

Comment: I don't think drag and drop works for inputs, it maybe an easier option to us jQuery as Dygestor has advised.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the onmouseup and onmousedown eventlisteners till the div is ready for activity. The syntax below should work for that

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mouseup", dragDropEnd)
document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mousedown", dragDropMove)
```